# importance of using macro STATIC

Tags: c, syntax, static

I have some legacy code, which uses the macro definition as

```
#ifdef def_STATIC
#define STATIC static
#else
#define STATIC
#else
#endif
```

I understand using `STATIC` will help limiting the scope of variables depending on `def_STATIC`
but in what cases is this practice used ?
How is it helpful ?

Comment: It would be good if you give a reference where did you find this macro definitions? Because if it is my code I do lots of mistakes :) Did you see in any standard library?

Comment: @Dayalrai The question isn't "What does static mean?" but "When would the macro shown above be useuful in a C project?"

Comment: This kind of macaroni tends to be used to solve linker problems.  Not much point in asking us to guess at its usage when you can *see* where that macro is used.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That is not me. BTW 6 upvote 1 close is rare combo. Anyways your answer below justifies the need of this MACRO.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : proprietary library code.

Comment: @Bleamer yes I notice It is fist time I saw this thanks for adding this information. Interesting!

Comment: @HansPassant : Out of inquisitivity was just trying to learn in what sort of hunger does this macaroni tastes best.

Comment: Not every piece of preprocessor insanity has usefulness. Lots of times it's just a case of somebody being stupid.

Comment: @R. But people here have quoted more than one insane instances. I hope one of those answers this.

Answer (score 8):

I have never faced such macro myself, but according to this: ["XFS removal of `#define STATIC static`"](http://oss.sgi.com/archives/xfs/2002-10/msg02063.html) source it was used to disable static functions because GDB couldn't properly debug static inline functions. That's why this macro was used to temporarily make them non-static.

Correct me if I'm wrong, I've just googled it :)
An interesting question really)

Comment: Though your link I read this I am adding here: "It used to help with old *`kdb`* (which didn't know about static functions). But since CONFIG_KALLSYMS was implemented this is obsolete. `gdb` should always know about static functions too." ...@issue [02068](http://oss.sgi.com/archives/xfs/2002-10/msg02068.html)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Thank you for adding this information. I wanted to mention `kdb` initially, but later in the discussion Keith Owens wrote that `kdb has no problems with static functions`. I guess that it's a good thing that both versions are now mentioned here, since we don't know for sure which one is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I believe the answer can definitely be improved.

Comment: @FreeNick: Yes I think he means new version of `kdb` because [here @ issue #02072](http://oss.sgi.com/archives/xfs/2002-10/msg02072.html) I read: "The use of `STATIC` to switch between `static` and `extern` is *deprecated*. Change `STATIC` to `static` in source, remove `-DSTATIC` from Makefiles, remove `#define` of `STATIC`."

Comment: @Bleamer, fair enough :) I hope that someone who used this kind of macro in practice will show up. I'm intrigued myself :)